# Android Studio AutoComplete Variable Naming

Tags: android, android-studio

the AutoComplete works well... but the naming of variables suck hard.

For example: 
- When you override methods, it shows like `(View view, ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)` instead of `(View view?, ViewGroup viewGroup?, int position)`

Where `?` means that i don't remember what was before.

I have Android Studio 1.4. I was working with 1.3.2 and everythink was ok! Now i have that problem.

PS: I changed 2-3 things about bracket formating. I guess that does not occurs the problem.... so whats the problem?

Lets say you create CustomAdapter extends BaseAdaptr. The getView method you wanna override is like this: 
`@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` .... IN MY ANDROID STUDIO IT IS `@Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)`

Comment: could you try explaining again your issue ?

Comment: Lets say you create CustomAdapter extends BaseAdaptr. The getView method you wanna override is like this: `@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` .... IN MY ANDROID STUDIO IT IS `@Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)`

Comment: it should take the same name from the super's method signature. Are you sure the signature of the super class is `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) `? I never saw `final` for the parameters of BaseAdapter's getView

Comment: Look this: Holy Moly http://pastebin.com/Gsyiz4gF